# Trying to make a script to add two tables together

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add two table's values together, and put them into one of them.
I have table 1 and table 2, I want to add them both together into table 1. I currently have one formlue but it isn't quite working.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange('C53:G72').getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange('C5:G24').getValue();
ss.getRange('C5:G24').setValue(num1+num2);
ss.getRange('C53:F71').setValue("0");
```

It only adds the values of cell C5 and C53, then pastes in into C5:G24, which is strange. Do I have to manually add each of the cells rather than generalise it with C5:G24 and C53:G72?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to manually add the values in each cells

[`Range.getValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) only returns the top-left cell in the provided range, as stated in the documentation

> Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. The value may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String depending on the value of the cell. Empty cells return an empty string.

[`Range.setValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) should only affect one cell, but it's not being stated in the doc.

You might be interested in [`Range.getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [`Range.setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) as these methods allow you to select and update multiple cell values at once

```
var ss           = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rangeA       = ss.getRange( 'C53:G72' );
var rangeB       = ss.getRange( 'C5:G24'  );
var rangeC       = ss.getRange( 'C53:F71' );
var rangeAValues = rangeA.getValues();
var rangeBValues = rangeB.getValues();
var rangeCValues = rangeC.getValues();

for ( var row in rangeAValues ) {
    for ( var col in rangeAValues[ row ] ) {
        rangeAValues[ row ][ col ] = ( +rangeAValues[ row ][ col ] || 0 ) + ( +rangeBValues[ row ][ col ] || 0 ); // Ensure that the result is numeric
    }
}

rangeB.setValues( rangeAValues );

// Assuming that you want to fill C53:F71 with "0"s
for ( var row in rangeCValues ) {
    for ( var col in rangeCValues[ row ] ) {
        rangeCValues[ row ][ col ] = "0";
    }
}

rangeC.setValues( rangeCValues );
```

Please note that a single `setValues` is more efficient than multiple `setValue`
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/42793831

Comment: This is 99% perfect, one small thing I guess I didn't mention is that some of the cells in tabel 1 have N/A in it, and table 2 have the 0s. So what it's doing is turning it into 0N/A, then when excecuted again, 00N/A, and again 000N/A. Is there something I can do about that?

Comment: Updated answer to ensure that the value is numeric. Default to 0 for non-numeric values (`N/A` for example)